# strange behavior when changing from JSF 2.0 to JSF 2.2

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have the following view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>

    <title>Revenue/Expenses Login</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/styles.css" />

</h:head>
<body>

    <h:form id="login">

        <!-- <p:graphicImage url="img/logog.JPG" width="448" height="119" /> -->

        <p id="paragraph">Enter username and password.</p>

        <p:outputLabel for="username" value="Username:" />

        <p:inputText id="username" value="#{loginController.login.tbcodusr}"
            required="true" requiredMessage="You must enter a Username." />

        <p:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:" />

        <p:password id="password" value="#{loginController.login.tbpswusr}"
            required="true" requiredMessage="You must enter a Password." />

        <p:messages autoUpdate="true" for="usuarioPassword" />

        <p:commandButton value="Login" action="#{loginController.login}" />

    </h:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Before I did any changes to the JSF version, the CSS was working fine. But now, when I go to the screen, the CSS is acting differently. The css looks like this:

```
body {
    font-family: Calibri;
    color: #555555;
}

.mainContainer{max-width: 1000px;margin:0 auto;}

h1 {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 32px;
    margin: 0.6em 0px 0.6em 0px;
    font-family: Calibri;
    display:block;
}

h2 {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 0.6em 0px 0.6em 0px;
    font-family: Calibri;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-style: italic;
    display:block;
}

a {
    color: #f20553;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: #D80649;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*login */

#login
{
    max-width: 500px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#login p
{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica;
}

#login label
{
    padding-top: 0.2em;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 0.1em;
    text-align: left;
    color: #262060;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica;
}

#login button
{
    margin-top: 0.2em;
}

#login input[type='text'], #login input[type='password']
{
    border:1px solid #CECECE;
    font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 200;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* login end */

.searchLink{font-size:12px;display:block;width: 9em;}

.containers{line-height: 2;}


.containers label{display:block;}
```

What happened when I upgraded to JSF 2.2? I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0) and followed instructions. What am I missing?

Also, when I click on the Login button, nothing happens. What is going on?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how we should help you. 'Strange behaviour' is not how a developer should describe/investigate things, same is true for 'nothing happens' and 'CSS is acting differently'. Besides all this, you seem to have mixed namespace declarations, pre 2.2 and 2.2. in the same page. And the link you post is from 1.2 to 2.0, not 2.0 to 2.2... Please improve your question

Comment: Indeed. Try to describe the problem as web developer, not as web enduser. The average web developer would press F12 in browser and check console and network tabs for clues. Please do the same and report anything which looks abormal to you. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info